# Not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode was thrown

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I created a sqlite database using an android app and I stored it in my external disk. The database name is sensor.sqlite and the file path is

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "data" + File.separator +"sensor.sqlite"
```

However in this line of code

```
 this.getWritableDatabase();
```

An exception -> not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode was thrown.

I have read related posts

[getWritableDatabase() VS getReadableDatabase()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597277/getwritabledatabase-vs-getreadabledatabase)

[Open Database for ReadWirte not possible on specific device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267861/open-database-for-readwirte-not-possible-on-specific-device)

But I haven't found an answer.

Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Regards,
Jimmy

This is my android manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <activity
        android:name="example.com.sensor.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="example.com.sensor.SensorActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is my code.

```
public SqlController(Context context) {
    super(context,
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "data" + File.separator +
                    "sensor.sqlite"
            , null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {


    String x = "CREATE TABLE [sport] ([id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,";
    x += " [accx] REAL,";
    x += " [accy] REAL,";
    x += " [accz] REAL,";
    x += " [geox] REAL,";
    x += " [geoy] REAL,";
    x += " [geoz] REAL,";
    x += " [activity] TEXT,";
    x += " [datetime] TIMESTAMP)";

    try {
        database.execSQL(x);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
    database.execSQL("drop table if exists sport");
    onCreate(database);
}

public void insert(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("accx", queryValues.get("accx"));
    values.put("accy", queryValues.get("accy"));
    values.put("accz", queryValues.get("accz"));
    values.put("geox", queryValues.get("geox"));
    values.put("geoy", queryValues.get("geoy"));
    values.put("geoz", queryValues.get("geoz"));
    values.put("activity", queryValues.get("activity"));
    values.put("datetime", new Date().toString());
    database.insert("sport", null, values);
    database.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you add Read/Write `File Permission`?

Add Permission in `AndroidManifest` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Please add more code to check whats happened @JimmyLee

Comment: I have update my question and included my android manifest file.

Comment: You only use `SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();` for Inserting? , Is this Line Necessary?

Comment: Ya, I want to insert a record.